# how to remove some parts in the url codeigniter routes htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, slug

Let say I have these urls in my website

http://www.example.com/locations

http://www.example.com/locations/sydney

http://www.example.com/locations/brisbane

http://www.example.com/locations/perth

http://www.example.com/services/

http://www.example.com/services/cars

http://www.example.com/services/truck

http://www.example.com/services/phone

http://www.example.com/blog

http://www.example.com/blog/display/blog-title

http://www.example.com/blog/display/blog-title2

http://www.example.com/blog/display/blog-title3

http://www.example.com/blog/display/blog-title4

what I want is the urls to be like these

http://www.example.com/locations

http://www.example.com/sydney

http://www.example.com/brisbane

http://www.example.com/perth

http://www.example.com/services/

http://www.example.com/cars

http://www.example.com/truck

http://www.example.com/phone

http://www.example.com/blog

http://www.example.com/blog-title

http://www.example.com/blog-title2

http://www.example.com/blog-title3

http://www.example.com/blog-title4

how to achieve this in codeigniter??

I've tried below code:

```
$route[''] = 'blog/index';
$route['(:num)'] = 'blog/index/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'blog/display/$1';
$route['home/(:any)'] = 'blog/display/$1';
```

but the problem is that only working for blogs cannot use the same code for others and it makes other links to be broken

so I tried @ACD answer it gave 2 errors
1. Undefined property: CI_Router::$load 
2. Call to a member function library() on null

so I made some modification like this

```
$req = $this->uri->segment(1);
require_once ( BASEPATH. 'database/DB.php');
$db =& DB();
if ($db->get_where('home_inner_tbl', array('page_url' => $req))) {
    $route['(:any)'] = 'home/display/$1';
} elseif ($db->get_where('blog_tbl', array('page_url' => $req))) {
    $route['(:any)'] = 'blog/blog_display/$1';
} elseif ($db->get_where('towing_services_tbl', array('page_url' => $req))) { 
$route['(:any)'] = 'towing-services/display/$1';
} elseif ($db->get_where('special_services_tbl', array('page_url' => $req))) {
$route['(:any)'] = 'cash-for-cars/display/$1';
} elseif ($db->get_where('locations_tbl', array('page_url' => $req))) {
$route['(:any)'] = 'locations/display/$1';
}
```

With this code it didn't give an error but only the first line of if statement that works which is the $route['(:any)'] = 'home/display/$1'; other link such as locatins, towing-services, blog, cash-for-cars don't work.

Is there something wrong with the if statement? cause it looks like this answer should be correct.

By the way my controller is looking like this

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{

public function index() {
// some code in here
}
public function display($page_url) {
// some code in here
}
}
```

Same looking controller goes to others (locations, blog, towing_services, etc)

as you can see I'm calling $page_url from the database.

Anyone can help me with this?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can filter first which route to take before creating the route if the request exists, assuming the url request can be fetched in the database (or change it to whatever measure you take to know if it exists on certain category):

```
$req = $this->uri->segment(1);
if ($this->db->get_where('locations_table', array('name' => $req))) {
    $route['(:any)'] = 'locations/$1';
} else if ($this->db->get_where('blogs_table', array('name' => $req))) {
    $route['(:any)'] = 'blog/display/$1';
} else if ($this->db->get_where('services_table', array('name' => $req))) {
    $route['(:any)'] = 'services/$1';
}
```

FYI: this can't be done with htaccess unless there's a specific format for each category (example: for location - loc_singapore, loc_usa; for services - svc_someservice etc)

Comment: Hi, I tried your code it gives me 2 errors
1. Undefined property: CI_Router::$load
2. Call to a member function library() on null

I wrote your code in routes.php, is it the correct place to write it?

it seems it doesn't understand $this->db->get_where parts. So I tried to $this->load->library('database'); but also didn't work. Any suggestion??. It seems you understood my question very well, can you help me please